# TRadioGroup: Click on current checked item twice to uncheck it. Can it be done?

Tags: delphi

I searched and couldn't find an answer for this:

I have four items in a radiogroup three of which are car names and the fourth item what I called "None". When the forth item is clicked, it sets the index to -1. This so far works fine. I wanted to have a feature where if I clicked an already checked item (activeindex), it will set it to -1. That way, I can remove the fourth "None" item from the list. Is this possible in radiogroup?

This should only work if the item clicked was already the index (old index) and it will be unchecked. If a non-checked item is clicked it will still set the index to that item.

Thanks!!

Comment: This isn't how Windows radio button controls work. Are you sure it is motivated to circumvent the default platform behaviour in this case?

Comment: You would either have to subclass TRadioGroup or make a custom control with radio buttons in a panel, I think.  It's a custom behaviour so it needs a custom component.  How about a combobox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard radio buttons do not behave like you describe.  Once a radio button is checked, is stays checked until another radio button in the same group is checked.

However, it is nonetheless *possible* to implement what you are asking for, with a little manual work:

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    RadioGroup1: TRadioGroup;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    OriginalWndProcs: array[0..2] of TWndMethod;
    procedure RadioButtonWndProc1(var Message: TMessage);
    procedure RadioButtonWndProc2(var Message: TMessage);
    procedure RadioButtonWndProc3(var Message: TMessage);
    procedure RadioButtonWndProc(const Index: Integer; var Message: TMessage);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TMyForm.RadioButtonWndProc1(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  RadioButtonWndProc(0, Message);
end;

procedure TMyForm.RadioButtonWndProc2(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  RadioButtonWndProc(1, Message);
end;

procedure TMyForm.RadioButtonWndProc3(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  RadioButtonWndProc(2, Message);
end;

procedure TMyForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewWndProcs: array[0..2] of TWndMethod;
  I: Integer;
begin
  NewWndProcs[0] := RadioButtonWndProc1;
  NewWndProcs[1] := RadioButtonWndProc2;
  NewWndProcs[2] := RadioButtonWndProc3;

  for I := 0 to 2 do
  begin
    OriginalWndProcs[I] := RadioGroup1.Buttons[I].WindowProc;
    RadioGroup1.Buttons[I].WindowProc := NewWndProcs[I];
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.RadioButtonWndProc(const Index: Integer; var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if (Message.Msg = CN_COMMAND) and
     (TWMCommand(Message).NotifyCode = BN_CLICKED) and
     (RadioGroup1.Buttons[Index].Checked) then
  begin
    RadioGroup1.Buttons[Index].Checked := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  OriginalWndProcs[Index](Message);
end;
```

---

**Update**: the above code can be simplified a bit, by passing the `TRadioButton` objects directly to `RadioButtonWndProc()` without needing to use intermediate proxy methods:

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    RadioGroup1: TRadioGroup;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    OriginalWndProcs: array[0..2] of TWndMethod;
    procedure RadioButtonWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TMyForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Btn: TRadioButton;
  M: TWndMethod;
begin
  for I := 0 to 2 do
  begin
    Btn := RadioGroup1.Buttons[I];
    Btn.Tag := I;

    OriginalWndProcs[I] := Btn.WindowProc;

    M := RadioButtonWndProc;
    TMethod(M).Data := Btn; // <-- makes Self in RadioButtonWndProc() point to the Button instead of the Form...
    Btn.WindowProc := M;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.RadioButtonWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  Btn: TRadioButton;
begin
  Btn := TRadioButton(Self);

  if (Message.Msg = CN_COMMAND) and
     (TWMCommand(Message).NotifyCode = BN_CLICKED) and
     (Btn.Checked) then
  begin
    Btn.Checked := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  MyForm.OriginalWndProcs[Btn.Tag](Message); // <-- note, using the global Form pointer to reach Form members...
end;
```

The code can be tweaked further if you want to support multiple radio groups:

```
type
  PRadioButtonInfo = ^TRadioButtonInfo;
  TRadioButtonInfo = record
    OriginalWndProc: TWndMethod;
  end;

  TRadioGroupInfo = record
    ButtonInfo: array of TRadioButtonInfo;
  end;

  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    RadioGroup1: TRadioGroup;
    RadioGroup2: TRadioGroup;
    // as many RadioGroups as you want...
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    GroupInfo: array of TRadioGroupInfo;
    procedure PrepareRadioGroup(GroupIndex: Integer; RadioGroup: TRadioGroup);
    procedure RadioButtonWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TMyForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(GroupInfo, 2); // as many groups as you need to have this non-standard behavior...
  PrepareRadioGroup(0, RadioGroup1);
  PrepareRadioGroup(1, RadioGroup2);
  // and so on...
end;

procedure TMyForm.PrepareRadioGroup(GroupIndex: Integer; RadioGroup: TRadioGroup);
var
  I: Integer;
  Btn: TRadioButton;
  M: TWndMethod;
begin
  with GroupInfo[GroupIndex] do
  begin
    SetLength(ButtonInfo, RadioGroup.Items.Count);

    for I := 0 to Length(ButtonInfo)-1 do
    begin
      Btn := RadioGroup.Buttons[I];

      ButtonInfo[I].OriginalWndProc := Btn.WindowProc;

      Btn.Tag := NativeInt(@ButtonInfo[I]); // <-- or Longint prior to XE2

      M := RadioButtonWndProc;
      TMethod(M).Data := Btn;
      Btn.WindowProc := M;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.RadioButtonWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  Btn: TRadioButton;
begin
  Btn := TRadioButton(Self);

  if (Message.Msg = CN_COMMAND) and
     (TWMCommand(Message).NotifyCode = BN_CLICKED) and
     (Btn.Checked) then
  begin
    Btn.Checked := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  PRadioButtonInfo(Btn.Tag).OriginalWndProc(Message);
end;
```

---

An alternative approach would be to subclass the `TRadioGroup` objects instead of the individual `TRadioButton` objects:

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    RadioGroup1: TRadioGroup;
    RadioGroup2: TRadioGroup;
    // as many RadioGroups as you want...
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    OriginalWndProcs: array of TWndMethod;
    procedure PrepareRadioGroup(GroupIndex: Integer; RadioGroup: TRadioGroup);
    procedure RadioGroupWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TMyForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(OriginalWndProcs, 2); // as many groups as you need to have this non-standard behavior...
  PrepareRadioGroup(0, RadioGroup1);
  PrepareRadioGroup(1, RadioGroup2);
  // and so on...
end;

procedure TMyForm.PrepareRadioGroup(GroupIndex: Integer; RadioGroup: TRadioGroup);
var
  I: Integer;
  M: TWndMethod;
begin
  RadioGroup.Tag := GroupIndex;

  OriginalWndProcs[GroupIndex] := RadioGroup.WindowProc;

  M := RadioGroupWndProc;
  TMethod(M).Data := RadioGroup;
  RadioGroup.WindowProc := M;
end;

procedure TMyForm.RadioGroupWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  Grp: TRadioGroup;
  Ctl: TWinControl;
  Btn: TRadioButton;
begin
  Grp := TRadioGroup(Self);

  if (Message.Msg = WM_COMMAND) and
     (TWMCommand(Message).NotifyCode = BN_CLICKED) then
  begin
    Ctl := FindControl(TWMCommand(Message).Ctl);

    if Ctl is TRadioButton then
    begin
      Btn := TRadioButton(Ctl);

      if Btn.Checked then
      begin
        Btn.Checked := False;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  MyForm.OriginalWndProcs[Grp.Tag](Message);
end;
```

---

Now, with all of that said, I would not recommend this UI design in the first place.  This is simply not how users expect radio buttons to behave.  A better UI choice would be to use a `TComboBox` instead, with a 4th item in it for selecting nothing.  A single `TComboBox` will take up less real-estate then multiple radio buttons, and it still offers the single-selection behavior that users expect.

Comment: This code works when the form has one radio group. Could you please tell me how to implement the same when i have more than more radio group in form. Thanks

Comment: @Amazing. your first solution for Multiple Radiogroups worked for me. Thanks a lot!
I would agree with your design with combobox. However, Sadly i can only change the logic but not the component in the existing project.